# What is the proper way to set S3 creds in Rails Development ENV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

What is the proper way to set S3 credentials in a Rails development enviroment.

I have

```
`config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    }
  }`
```

in `config/environments/development.rb`

but would like to know where to actually set `S3_BUCKET_NAME`, etc

Comment: In development I just quickly set those in ~/.bash_profile like SE_BUCKET_NAME="my-bucket-name" and then run `source ~/.bash_profile`. In production there are better options through gems.

Comment: Ya, I had thought about doing that, but am really digging figaro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend the [figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) gem.  As a bonus it works great with Heroku, too.

Comment: really enjoy this little "gem" that you have found.  And all pun is intended.

Answer (score 0):

I store mine in an external file that gets read in on boot, with a fallback using config/env.rb for defaults.  These two gems do the trick for me.  The latter adds some nice stuff like whining if an ENV var isn't set that you think should be set.

```
gem 'dotenv-rails'
gem 'env_bang-rails'
```